# Tableau Geographic Mapping does not show whole map

Tags: tableau-api

From most tableau tutorials they just drag "state" to the row and there's a map (an example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHe0jFgVPJU

But when I drag "state" into row or column, the only thing showing is just the little state maps instead of the whole map.

[image]

Also like this:

[image]

I have tried just drag "longitude" and "latitude" into column and row, and still no map showing up, only an empty coordinate axis.

[image]

The data is like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you please share a bit of your state data?

Comment: Starting from a fresh worksheet, try just double clicking on state - instead of dragging it anywhere. There is a lot more to mapping in tableau, but that’s the easiest way to start

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have added a screenshot of the state data, they are just state names

Comment: @AlexBlakemore yes I have tried that.. but the result is still a bunch of tiny state maps :(

Comment: Check that your background map server is set to tableau (and not set to none) — see the map menu